# Javascript: Iterate through binary tree?

Tags: javascript

How can I iterate through the following if I want to print all the pitches in order such that the left comes first and then right. For the following first piece of code; the answer should be a4, b4,c4,d4. How can I achieve this programmatically?

```
var melody2_mus = 
    { tag: 'seq',
      left: 
       { tag: 'seq',
         left: { tag: 'note', pitch: 'a4', dur: 250 },
         right: { tag: 'note', pitch: 'b4', dur: 250 } },
      right:
       { tag: 'seq',
         left: { tag: 'note', pitch: 'c4', dur: 500 },
         right: { tag: 'note', pitch: 'd4', dur: 500 } } }
```

Another Example:

```
 var melody2_mus = 
        { tag: 'seq',
          left: { tag: 'note', pitch: 'b4', dur: 250 } },
          right:
           { tag: 'seq',
             left: { tag: 'note', pitch: 'c4', dur: 500 },
             right: { tag: 'note', pitch: 'd4', dur: 500 } } }
```

should print b4, c4, d4

Thanks

Comment: Tried in-order depth first traversal? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#In-order

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A recursive function would be simplest:

```
function traverse(obj) {
    // always follow left branch first
    if (obj.left) {
        traverse(obj.left);
    }

    // do stuff for leaf nodes
    if (obj.pitch) {
        console.log(obj.pitch);
    }

    // then the right branch if it exists
    if (obj.right) {
        traverse(obj.right);
    }
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/E2ZEB/

Or more generically:

```
function traverse(obj, func) {
    if (!obj) return;

    traverse(obj.left, func);
    func(obj);
    traverse(obj.right, func);
}
```

Comment: I even would expect a node *either* to be a leaf with a `pitch` *or* have both `left` and `right` children. Btw, your post-order traversal is not the most intuitive :-)

Comment: @Alnitak: Ahh, if he only stores the data in leaf nodes, then I believe you're right.

Comment: @Thanks Alnitak, my data is only stored in leaf nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a copy of Alnitak's answer, but abstracted with the visitor pattern.

```
function traverse(obj, cb) {
    cb(obj);
    if (obj.left) {
        traverse(obj.left, cb);
    }
    if (obj.right) {
        traverse(obj.right, cb);
    }
}

var melody2_mus = 
    { tag: 'seq',
      left: 
       { tag: 'seq',
         left: { tag: 'note', pitch: 'a4', dur: 250 },
         right: { tag: 'note', pitch: 'b4', dur: 250 } },
      right:
       { tag: 'seq',
         left: { tag: 'note', pitch: 'c4', dur: 500 },
         right: { tag: 'note', pitch: 'd4', dur: 500 } } }

traverse(melody2_mus, function(node) {
    if (node.pitch) {
        console.log(node.pitch);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E2ZEB/3/

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to call `cb` _between_ the `.left` and `.right` nodes in the general case when a node may also have a value.

Comment: @Alnitak It depends on the type of traversal needed, doesn't it? Just move it around for the right traversal type?

Comment: when a node can have a value it would be higher than the left node's value (and descendants thereof) and lower than the right node's values.  The order doesn't matter, though, if the branch nodes can't have a value.

Comment: @Alnitak, traversing through the `tag` properties seems to work fine as I have it http://jsfiddle.net/E2ZEB/4/ I get "seq, seq, note, note, seq, note, note" (source order)

Comment: when the binary tree is being used to store sorted data, `c4` should come before the third `seq` and then `d4` after that.  This is not the same as 'source order'.  See http://jsfiddle.net/E2ZEB/5/

Comment: @Alnitak I don't quite understand what you mean, is this tree used to store sorted data? It doesn't look it? It looks like two part harmony?

Comment: Yes, but that's why I qualified this "in the general case".